# C# command line add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Need to work with Excel automation using C#.
There is no Visual Studio installation, and can't be done. But Ms-Office 2007 is installed at workstation.
While using csc.exe for compilation, getting errors, because of Microsoft.Office assembly. 
I tried searching at general locations, but could not locate dll file.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

/// no files found
/// assembly paths ; C:\Windows\assembly\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
/// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

        // Insert VBA code here.

        excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should reference the dll as you call csc with the /r parameter

Comment: Yes, I am using E:\csharp>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /r:C:\Windows\assembly\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll helloworld.cs [But it fails because of reference problem.]

Comment: Not an answer to your question but something you should know when working with the Excel Introp: http://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/2594742

Comment: I don't understand why you don't reference the interop DLL? Add Reference > Microsoft Office 12/14. [Here is more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13328392/495455). BTW VS2012 doesn't have the Setup/Deployment Wizard thats included with VS2010 you need to use something else to deploy the VSTO add-in or COM component like WIX with recent versions of Visual Studio (ie versions > VS2010).

Answer (score 2):

you can reference the DLL which is located in the GAC
    csc /recurse:* /r:"C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Inte
    5.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"

Depending on you office version you have eventually to change the path a bit

Comment: path - C:\windows\assembly\ doesn't have any folder or dll of above name.
It cotains list of assemblies only. And right click gives option to Uninstall them and see their properties.

Comment: it is hidden --> make Windows key + r --> paste "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL" --> enter

Comment: I found dll @ locaiton: C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0.dll.So while compiling I added reference as per your instructions. Now error comes like this : The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?) and The type or namespace name 'Excel' could not
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: If I try writing < using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0; > its not legal to write.