# How to allow excel data modification in manual as well as programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, com-interop, excel-interop

I am using C# windows application for Excel data add/update. I had added `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference(Reference -> Right Click -> Add Reference -> COM -> Type Libraries -> Microsoft Excel 1X.0 Object Libraries). On my form, I have one panel control `panel1`, one List-box `lstSamples` and two button `btnAddSample`, `btnFormatWorksheet`.

My sample code is as below:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
    Workbook excelWorkBook;
    Worksheet excelWorkSheet;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadExcelFile();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    private void LoadExcelFile()
    {
        excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
        excelApp.EnableAutoComplete = false;
        excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        IntPtr excelHwnd = new IntPtr(excelApp.Application.Hwnd);
        SetParent(excelHwnd, panel1.Handle);
    }

    private void btnAddSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        excelWorkSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        int lastUsedRow = excelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        excelWorkSheet.Cells[lastUsedRow + 1, 1] = lstSamples.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lstSamples.Items.Remove(lstSamples.SelectedItem);
    }

   private void btnFormatWorksheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Range chartRange;
        excelWorkSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        chartRange = excelWorkSheet.get_Range("b2", "e9");
        chartRange.BorderAround(XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, 
        XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, 
        XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);

    }
}
```

Please follow the steps as I mentioned 1. Run the application and add data in "A1" cell (Which is of string type) 2. Again add some data in "A2" cell and Press enter 3. Select one item from `lstSamples` listbox and click on `btnAddSample` (Result is like selected item will get added into "A3" cell 4. Try to modify "A1" or "A2" cell data. (Here `lstSample` is having items of string type like Test1, Test2, Test3,....). If you are able to edit cells then click on `btnFormatWorksheet` then try to edit any cell.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. How exactly does the file get opened as read-only? You're not even saving the file in your code. Do you save it manually and then click the `btnAddSample` button?

Comment: 1) How is it read-only if the file is not saved (or do you save it before clicking the button?) 2) Please be specific about how you determine it's actually open in read-only mode. For instance, does it say "[read-only]" in the title? Are you not able to modify a cell? Are you not able to save? Etc.

Comment: Actually that file is not saved any where, even if I don't know what was file mode "[read-only]" or "[read-write]", but I'm not able to do the modification manually (not able to modify cell)once that code block is executed.

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce that? What value is selected in `lstSamples` when you click the button? Does it get into the sheet successfully? Also, can you please elaborate on the _"I'm not able to do the modification manually"_ part? Can you actually type in a cell or not? If not, what happens when you activate Excel and **double click** an empty cell?

Comment: Repeating yourself in comments doesn't help anyone. It would be much more helpful if you would [edit] your question and include the answers to the questions you've been asked in the comments to provide the additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you referencing the COM DLL? You should be referencing the .Net **PIA's** - the Primary Interop Assemblies in this location, via the .Net tab in the References window and browse to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [version]\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office[version]\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Only for unit testing do you reference the COM one. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256597/495455) and [how I originally worked it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328392/495455). It's easy to get confused because in Solution Explorer they are both called the same thing!

[image]

---

If that doesn't work, I originally put this as an answer to save other peoples time being wasted.

**Both Ahmed and I cannot reproduce the problem you described with the code you have provided.**

See I typed in cells A1 and A2, then I selected an item in the list and clicked the button. Then I select the cell A2 and type Editable.

[image]

ps If you can provide the steps to reproduce I'll be happy to take another look at it.

## UPDATE:

Your revised steps to reproduce the problem are incorrect, it works for me:

[image]

## UPDATE 2:

Check if the message pump filters are causing the focus to go to another cell/control:

[Excel CustomTaskPane with WebBrowser control - keyboard/focus issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30948205/495455)

Comment: I had updated question. Just add one more button `btnFormatWorksheet` and write the code as I updated in code block then try to edit cell. I hope you will get the same problem.Please help me, I really don't know what was going on.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but this is now its turning into a chameleon question, there's only so many times you can lead people up the garden path. Our time is valuable, I suggest **YOU try on another PC**.

Comment: Thx for giving ur valuable time, but still I'm facing same issue, unable to find root cause. All excels cells are non-editable every time I'm going to 'Name Box' and 'Formula Bar' to edit cell data.

Comment: I'll level out the downvote. You didn't confirm COM or PIA or if another PC works and I can't reproduce so I am unable to assist further. Check my update 2 that could be the cause.

Comment: @Kiran - did you have any luck in the end? I didn't hear back.

Comment: @JeremyThompson "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office" This folder is empty, so I added reference from COM -> Type Libraries. `btnAddSample_Click` working fine as expected but code from`btnFormatWorksheet` will lock excel and I'm not able to edit. I don't know exact root cause of this issue. Even if same problem in other machine as well. I'm using VS 2015 and MS Office 2013, Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: No, no, no. You need to install Visual Studio with the MS Office Tools, that's why it's missing. First thing I showed you was the massive mission I put into working out the COM reference is wrong (it's only right for Unit Test projects). **YOU NEED THE PIA's** referenced in your WinForms app.

Comment: I spent so much time on this and you didn't even confirm my first troubleshooting step... Yet you'll spend 50 rep asking for help. I don't really get it. To become good at programming "I go after problems like a dog after a bone". And I highlighted the confusing part with same names shown in Solution Explorer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you so much for ur efforts, I'll reinstall VS with MS Office tools option and get you back.